# Are there any iPhone cases compatible with full-body iPhone films (i.e. films on the sides)?

Tags: iphone, hardware-recommendation, accessories, case

I am a kind of person who likes to keep their phone out without a case most of the time (except for outdoor sporting trips), so I have a full body invisible shield which does NOT work well with any cases I try because of the added size on the antenna sides. The best solution I found was the Defender OtterBox, but that renders the invisible shield ruined after applying the case. Does anyone know of cases designed with full body shields in mind?

Comment: I thought the whole point have having a full body invisible shield is that you wouldn't need any case. Am I misreading your question?

Comment: Well you don't need the case for day-to-day use, but when I am rock climbing, I think I would prefer to have that added protection - you know...the thin pieces of film won't help my phone if it falls or hits a rock or if sand gets into the ports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people I know of that appreciate the invisible shield type skins go for a sleeve as their secondary protection method.

I have seen very nice ones made DIY style from all [manner of foam](http://www.rei.com/product/374053/standard-blue-foam-pad-regular) - the more risky a sport, the more padding you can include. It's cheap, light and only as bulky as you need. A simple strap will keep your phone in the sleeve and you can waterproof with a bag as needed.

The nature of the soft sticky films is that they grip most hard cases and result in the damage you are seeing to the skin when a hard plastic case gets fitted over the phone.

If foam isn't your preference, sleeves from felt and leather are also widely available from reputable retail and internet sellers, etsy, ebay. Don't overlook the potential to have your local craftsmen or craftswomen make a sleeve to your exact specifications for a reasonable cost.